Axios Cache Interceptor Revalitadion
Good evening everyone, I'm in a NEXT.JS project and I'm using the Axios Cache Interceptor exporting an Axios instance with setupCache and a 60-minute ttl being stored in localStorage.
However, I need the revalidation to be done when there is new data in the endpoint return in order to revalidate the cache.
If I'm not mistaken, SWR behaves like this, revalidating when there is something new, but I need to keep using Axios, does anyone know how to solve this case?
Below is setupCache configuration and application.
At this moment, nothing special.
